# String replacing pattern matching doesn't work in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to replace the host address of an ip address.I tried as below in a bash command line window and it works fine:

```
$ baseIp="10.215.5.16"
$ ip=18
$ echo ${baseIp/%\.+([0-9])/\."$ip"}
```

But when I write a bash script as blow,it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

baseIp="10.215.5.16"
ip=18

currIp=${baseIp/%\.+([0-9])/\."$ip"}

echo $currIp
```

It prints:

```
$ ./test.sh
10.215.5.16
```

Thanks

Comment: Your non-script example prints "10.215.5.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using an extended glob expression. Extended globs are not enabled by default; you may have them enabled in your .bashrc and/or .bash_profile, but that doesn't affect the script. Add `shopt -s extglob` at the beginning of the script.

BTW, you also don't need to escape the `.` character in either the pattern or the replacement, but (as @CostiCiudatu pointed out) you are missing it in the replacement in the script. Also, double-quoting `$ip` but leaving the whole expression unquoted doesn't make much sense. I'd recommend this:

```
echo "${baseIp/%.+([0-9])/.$ip}"
```